# How do UnknownCategoricalLevels affect the confidence values of H2O model predictions

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

I am using a DRF model generated with `h2o flow`. When running fresh input data against this model (using its MOJO in a java program with the [EasyPredictModelWrapper](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/easy/EasyPredictModelWrapper.java)), there are a large number of `UnknownCategoricalLevels` (checking with the `getUnknownCategoricalLevelsSeen()` and `getUnknownCategoricalLevelsSeenPerColumn()` [methods](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/easy/EasyPredictModelWrapper.java#L199)).

My workaround for this was to only use those predictions that had a prediction confidence above a certain threshold (say 0.90). Ie. the [classProbability](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/easy/EasyPredictModelWrapper.java#L397) selected by the model must be grater than threshold to be used.

My questions are:

1. Is this solution wrong-headed (ie. does not actually address/workaround the problem (eg. `unknownlevels` don't actually affect the class probability values)) or is it a *valid* workaround to the problem?
2. Is there a better way to address this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unknown categorical level is treated as an NA for that column.

Without knowing the details of your data (including the cost implications of false positives and false negatives), I wouldn't say that you need to threshold rows that have NAs any differently than for rows that do not.  (The NA is already handled quite well by DRF.)

Note the built-in threshold is max-F1 (not 0.5).  So if you are changing the threshold for rows with unknown values, it's relative to max-F1 (not 0.5).  Using your own threshold is certainly a valid approach.

If you want to visualize your trees to more easily see how the NAs behave, you can do so following the instructions here:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/overview-summary.html#viewing-a-mojo

There are also other strategies for dealing with it, like target-encoding your categorical input column and treating an NA as the average target value.  (This effectively turns a categorical variable into a numeric one, but requires you to preprocess the data.)

Comment: Just for extra clarification, when you say *"So if you are changing the threshold for rows with unknown values, it's relative to max-F1 (not 0.5)."* Do you mean that if I were to use the model's MOJO in java code and set a custom threshold (for say, max_mean_perclass_accuracy) of t0 with a line like `return (p.classProbabilities[1] >= t0) ? 1: 0;`, then the model would actually be using a threshold of maxF1+t0 or just that the default threshold is maxF1? Thanks.

Comment: I changed the word "default" to "built-in".  The MOJO only knows max-F1 baked in.  The predicted class from the MOJO is based on max-F1.  So you have to write your own piece of code comparing p.classProbabilities[1], as you show above, to use a different threshold for deciding the predicted class.